# Can't get length of array/object in an Object of Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variable-length-array

```js
box = {
  curBox: 0,
  boxes: document.getElementsByClassName('box'),
  size: this.boxes.length, //this one won't work
  orSize: Object.keys(this.boxes).length, //as well as this one
  preBox: function() {
    curBox -= 1
  },
  nexBox: function() {
    curBox += 1
  }
}

console.log(box.boxes.length); //This one works well!!!
```

```html
<div class='active box BG_blue'>
  <meta name='title' content='Overview' /> ...
</div>

<div class='inactive box BG_orange'>
  <meta name='title' content='Career' /> ...
</div>

<div class='inactive box BG_red'>
  <meta name='title' content='Skills' /> ...
</div>

<div class='inactive box BG_awesome'>
  <meta name='title' content='Hobbies' /> ...
</div>
```

I tried to get the length of an array returned from `getElementsByClassName`. If I put it outside the object range, it work. But inside the object range, it won't. Right now, I would like to know a reason how come. I've test on other site (such as [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)) code editor but it only return the same result.

Comment: because `this` doesn't point to the `box` object. `this` points to the window object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main reson is you are still initializing you Box object hence you can't access this. In other words your object is not fully formed at the time you are using this.

what you can do is create a function and return it.

```
boxes: function() {
  return function() { return this.boxes.length; },
}
```

I created a jsfiddle with improvements. https://jsfiddle.net/jz1thu26/.

also note that you need to run your method when DOM is ready.

Comment: this is not going to work. again `this` will not point to the box object, it will likely be undefined or the Window object, if you tried it then you will know
Edited: Sweko was right

Comment: Yes, you will need a regular function, as the fat arrow does not define its own `this`

Comment: @SWeko forgot about that :) awesome!

Answer (score 2):

`this` in javascript has only function scope, i.e, it points to the object where the currently executing function resides. If you do not have such an object, i.e. you are at the top level, then `this`, in a browser, generally points to the `window` object.

So, while your object is being constructed, `this` is not actually your object, but something else.

Code like this will work:

```
const person = {
  name: "Wekoslav",
  surname: "Stefanovski",
  getName: function(){
    return this.name + " " + this.surname;
  }
}

console.log(person.getName());
```

because I'm calling the `getName` function only after I've defined it, and within that function, `this` is bound to `person`. However, this code:

```
const person = {
  name: "Wekoslav",
  surname: "Stefanovski",
  fullName: this.name + " " + this.surname;
}

console.log(person.fullName);
```

won't work, because this is bound to whatever it was before the `const person` line got executed.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('box')` is incorrect and return null in this case. That function returns elements which have all of the classes specified in the first argument as a space-separated string. You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.box')`.

Comment: dude, it returns an HTML collection and it's an object, so there's nothing wrong with what he's doing, only that he's calling `this` inside the object initialization

Comment: @Roljhon Did you test `document.getElementsByClassName('box')` in console? It returns null.

Comment: dude, it didn't :) probably you're executing the code outside of the iframe if you're testing it from the fiddle above.